# Can I use multiple Layouts for different pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js

For Example: If I want to have two different types of Nav-Bars for the Shopping area & User settings area.

Comment: Of course you can, simply render whichever components you like. Do you have a more specific question and/or example of your use-case?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `pages/_app.js` to share a layout across *all* pages, but if you have multiple layouts, you could either:

- Extract your layout to a child of `_app.js`. For example, `pages/index.js` would render your `<Layout />` component there instead of in `_app.js`. Then, `pages/blog.js` could render a different layout `<BlogLayout />`.
- You could use the `useRouter()` hook inside `_app.js` to check which route you're on and conditionally change the layout.

Comment: Hey, can you give an example of the first approach?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/layout-component